# Is this the correct way to understand what i have just done

Tags: investing, trading, starting-out-investing

So im quite knew to Investment and Trading and have discovered some applications to start off with...1 of which is Trading212. I decided for obvious reasons to start of with a training account

If im thinking correctly from the screenshot  i bought 5000 shares of Microsoft for an avg price of $153.09?? 
but when i sold them all i made a profit of $8737.65 is this the correct logical thinking. because it doesn't make sense ..surely the total price 5k*the price is the amount of money put in ...right

[image: this is the image]?

And of course with more practise do you think i should turn to real trading

I also used Libertex and have made many successful trades on there as well (training account)...just not sure if i'm ready to make the jump yet.

And yes i heard Libertex has bad reviews that's why i'm trying to get my head around trading.

thanks for any help

Comment: According to the screen shot your profit is being reported in GBP although you are trading in USD, so while you made a profit of USD10,900, this is equivalent to GBP8,737.85 at an exchange rate of 1.2473....

Comment: so my logic was correct excluding the exchange ?

Comment: Well, yes.  The gross profit or loss is the difference in the buy and sell price times the number of shares sold.  For tax purposes you can net off trading commissions and any other trading costs.

Answer (score 2):

The screen shows a conversion of currency.

Consider this: 5000x(155.27 close - 153.09 ave price) = 10900 dollars gain

10900/8737.85 = 1.25 dollars per pound conversion rate